# Read fingerprint as string in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, hash, fingerprint, sha

I have an app running on android that authenticate with fingerprint. The app is working and it's returning what I want. But I still want to read the fingerprint hashed or as string so I can hash it for another project. My code so far:

main.dart

```
import 'package:fingerprint/secondpage.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
  import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

  void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         home: FingerprintApp(),
         ));
   }

 class FingerprintApp extends StatefulWidget{


 @override
 _FingerprintAppState createState() => _FingerprintAppState();


}


class _FingerprintAppState extends State<FingerprintApp>{

LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();

bool _canCheckBiometric ;

List<BiometricType> _availableBiometrics;
String autherized = "Not autherized";

Future<void> _checkBiometric() async {
  bool canCheckBiometric;
  try {
     canCheckBiometric = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
if (!mounted) return;
setState(() {
  _canCheckBiometric = canCheckBiometric;
});
}

Future<void> _getAvailableBiometric() async {
  List<BiometricType> availableBiometric;

  try{

    availableBiometric = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
  } on PlatformException catch (e){
    print(e);
  }
  setState(() {
    _availableBiometrics = availableBiometric;
  });
}

Future<void> _authenticate() async{
  bool authenticated = false;
  try{
    authenticated = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: "Scan your finger to authenticate",
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: false
    );
  } on PlatformException catch(e){
    print(e);
  }

  if (!mounted) return;

  setState(() {
    autherized = authenticated ? "Autherized success":"Failed to authenticate";
    if(authenticated){
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
    }

    print(autherized);
  });
}


@override

void initState(){
  _checkBiometric();
  _getAvailableBiometric();
}









@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Color(0xFF07496D),
     body: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 24.0),
       child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text("Login",style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 48.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold

            ),),
          ),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/fingerprint.png',
                      width: 120.0,
                    ),
                    Text("Fingerprint Auth", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),),
                    Container(
                      width: 150.0,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                      child: Text("Authenticate with your fingerprint instead of your password",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 1.5,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0 ),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: _authenticate,
                            elevation: 0.0,
                            color: Color(0xFF04A5ED),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:14.0,horizontal: 24.0),
                              child: Text("Authenticate", style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
     ) ,
    ),
  );
 }

}
```

androidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fingerprint">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"></uses-permission>

    
   <application
        android:label="fingerprint"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  local_auth: ^0.4.0+1
```

When I run this app, it takes a fingerprint and accept that I move to another page. But is there any way to read the fingerprint in sha256 or sha1 or as string? I want to save this fingerprint in a file for future use.

Comment: "But is there any way to read the fingerprint in sha256 or sha1 or as string?" -- not on Android, with built-in fingerprint support. You may be able to do this with an external fingerprint reader with its own SDK.

Comment: @commonsWare thank you for answering. Can you give me some examples of built-in fingerprint support ?

Comment: "Can you give me some examples of built-in fingerprint support ?" -- you appear to have it in your question.

Comment: @J1701 I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?